# Click through shape to select the underlying shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an on click event on my rectangles but in some places, I can't select them because other shapes overlapping them.
I can identify all my shapes somehow, f.e. by ID, etc.

Can I somehow click trough shapes to select the underlying shape, like with attribute pointer-events = none for text?
Or put my rectangles on top of everything else?

I append my paths from a single Geojson-file like this:

```
svgContainer.selectAll(null)
                    .data(feat.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 0.1)
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("PENr", function (d) {
                        return d.properties.Nr
                    })
                    .attr("myID", function (d) {
                        return d.properties.ID;
                    })
                    .style("pointer-events", "visible")
                    .on("click", click);
```

Comment: The problem is, if you put your rectangles above everything, it will display it on top (so other things will be hidden). A good way is to set **pointer-events: none;** to everything except rect which will be **fill** or whatever is the best for you. Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: pointer-events: none works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add onclick event to parent element and handle everything there. Property `event.target` references to element that actually fired event, if you need to know it.